# Is there a comprehensive description for log4j.properties options?

Tags: log4j

I have Googled till my finger bleed if I could not find a comprehensive description of the option usable for `log4j.properties`. All I find a general overview and samples from existing projects.

Among my questions are:

1. Which `%` place-holder are available `log4j.appender.*.layout.ConversionPattern`
2. Which type of layouter are available for `log4j.appender.*.layout`
3. Are there any `%` place-holder available for `log4j.appender.*.file`

Maybe I just used the wrong search terms so just having a link to right place would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

See the API docs at the link below.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html

Basically, your configuration in a properties file will look much like if you set all the configuration via code, which is why the API docs should answer all your questions.